# wlan0 does NOT show up on iwconfig

Tags: atheros, wireless

OS: UBUNTU 11.10

HW:

1. SDIO WiFi dongle with Atheros AR6103 module
2. PCI to SDIO adapter board

Problem: The system does not recognize the WiFi dongle although the adapter board is sensing the dongle insertion by turning on a LED

Additional information:

`root@GIGABYTE:/home/ady# ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:e5:49:c0:2d:55  
          inet addr:192.168.1.159  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::52e5:49ff:fec0:2d55/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4669 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5455223 (5.4 MB)  TX bytes:258681 (258.6 KB)
          Interrupt:40 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`root@GIGABYTE:/home/ady# iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`root@GIGABYTE:/home/ady# lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 30)
04:01.0 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
04:01.1 SD Host controller: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI SmartMedia / xD Card Reader Controller
04:01.2 FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc Memory Stick Card Reader Controller
05:00.0 USB Controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: This is quite a long shot, but you might need this kernel patch: http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff;h=18ee684b8ab666329e0a0a72d8b70f16fb0e2243

Comment: have you consulted https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo

Answer (score 1):

Try `ifconfig wlan0 up` or `ifconfig ath0 up`.

Comment: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

Comment: @JohnJoe this is a very old Q/A and commands and interface naming conventions have changed. Create a new question with your specific details.